# Javascript check if a class name has been added to DIV and perform task

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, setinterval, contains

I have the following functions:

```
<div class="chat-box"></div>

setInterval(() => {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "processes/get-chat.php", true);
  xhr.onload = ()=> {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {
        let data = xhr.response;
        chatBox.innerHTML = data;
        // if(!chatBox.classList.contains("active")) {}
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("incoming_id=" + incoming_id);
}, 500);

if(chatBox.classList.contains("active")) {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"fast");
}
```

I want to check if the `chatbox` div has the class name `active` and move to the bottom of the div automatically. The `active` class is being added from the `setInterval` function. However, I cannot the if condition inside the `setInterval` function because it will then be executed ever `n` amount of time and then I won't be able to scroll up and read the contents. It will take me to the bottom every `n` seconds. Therefore, I want the scroll to bottom to be executed only once. For this, I have placed it outside of `setInterval` function. But, this does not seem to be working. What can be the issue here? How can I make this work? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I suspect that your chatbox div is empty at the point where its calling the scroll. Did you have this working previously when it was in your setInterval method? If so and you only want it to run once, can't you add a global variable that gets set to true/false so that it only scrolls the once. After that check against your variable to see if you should scroll down.

Comment: If you move your scroll outside setInterval, then it will run once, but it will run before the setInterval runs and therefore before the ajax request and therefore before the class has been set.

Comment: @Nathelol you suspected it right. Also, before I could try your logic myself @ ikik posted an answer with the same logic as yours. I have accepted it. Thanks :)

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for that info... Educational :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of things can easily be done by adding additional logic and counter.

You define outside variable `let count = 0;`

Then inside the interval you add +1 every time. And then add this to your if to react only once, when count is 1.

```
++count
        if (chatBox.classList.contains("active") && count === 1) {
```

```js
< div class = "chat-box" > < /div>

let count = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "processes/get-chat.php", true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        let data = xhr.response;
        chatBox.innerHTML = data;
        ++count
        if (chatBox.classList.contains("active") && count === 1) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
          }, "fast");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("incoming_id=" + incoming_id);
}, 500);
```

OR true false logic, you get the picture:

```js
< div class = "chat-box" > < /div>

let count = true;

setInterval(() => {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "processes/get-chat.php", true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        let data = xhr.response;
        chatBox.innerHTML = data;
        
        if (chatBox.classList.contains("active") && count === true) {
        count = false;
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
          }, "fast");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("incoming_id=" + incoming_id);
}, 500);
```

Comment: I prefer the `true....false` logic just for avoiding the numbers and keeping it simpler... However, for some reason in my case it was `if(!chatBox.....)` the `NOT` symbol necessary here as commented in my question in the `setInterval` part. End of the line, worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: Adding an additional opinion:  `let scrolled = false` ... `scrolled = true`   (slightly confusing name "count=true", but only there for the code demo reusing the previous code).   Or `let scrollNeeded=true` .. `scrollNeeded=false` so you don't have `if (!scrolled` if you don't like the `if (!` construct.  Try not to use negative variable names as they can be even more confusing.   `let notScrolled=true` `notScrolled=false` `if (!notScrolled...` err.. :)